# Python, finding all combinations of two arrays without using intertools

Tags: python, arrays

> I have a two dimensional array and a one dimensional array. I need to >find the combinations of the two and add that to another array. So for >instance the two arrays a[[1,2],[3,4]] and b[5,6] I should get array >c[[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[3,4,5],[3,4,6]]. I have written code for this but >what I end up getting is c[[1,2,5,6],[1,2,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6]]. I'm >a bit new to python which is why I think I'm having so many problems.

> the code I have so far

```
b = [11, 14]
c = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]
f = []


for x in range(0, len(c)):
    d = []
    for y in range(0, len(c[0])):
        d.append(c[x][y])        
    for z in range(0, len(b)):
        e = d
        e.append(b[z])
        f.append(e)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `copy()` function :

```
e = d.copy()
```

Check the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html